# Random walks - What is the probability that a path, for most of the time, is close to the origin?

Tags: probability, random-walk

Let the grid of our possible positions be $\mathbb Z ^2$. Let $(0,0)$ be our starting point.
In each turn, we move with equal probability either one up, down, to the left or to the right.

Let $r\in\mathbb{N}$ be the maximal distance regarding $||\cdot ||_1$, which we see as "close to the origin" . 
We define $A_n$ to be the event that a random walk of length $n$ is for more in half of its steps in the square $S:=\{i\in\mathbb N: ||i||_1\le r\}$

I'm looking for the probability that an infinitely long random walk is for more of half its steps in the square $S$, i.e. for the value of:
$$ 
\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb P (A_n)
$$

Even finding a useful formal characterization of $A_n$ strikes me as difficult.
One not that's probably not that useful is the following.:
$$
A_n =\{\pmatrix{\binom {i_{1,1}}{i_{1,2}}\\...\\ \binom{i_{n,1}}{i_{n,2}}}\in(\mathbb  Z^2)^n: 
\binom {i_{1,1}}{i_{1,2}}=\binom 00 \quad\land\quad
\forall k\in \{1,...,n-1\}: \left|\left|\binom{i_{k,1}}{i_{k,2}}-\binom{i_{k+1,1}}{i_{k+1,2}}\right|\right|_1 =1 \quad\land \quad \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbf{1}_{ S}\binom{i_{k,1}}{i_{k,2}}\ge \frac n2\}
$$

For which we'd have to define for each $n$ the probability space $(\Omega_n,P(\Omega_n),\mathbb P_n)$ with 
$$\Omega_n:= \{\pmatrix{\binom {i_{1,1}}{i_{1,2}}\\...\\ \binom{i_{n,1}}{i_{n,2}}}\in(\mathbb  Z^2)^n:
\binom {i_{1,1}}{i_{1,2}}=\binom 00 \quad\land\quad 
\forall k\in \{1,...,n-1\}: \left|\left|\binom{i_{k,1}}{i_{k,2}}-\binom{i_{k+1,1}}{i_{k+1,2}}\right|\right|_1 =1 \}$$

For the classic formulation with the result space for $A_n$ being $\{\{0,1\}^n\}$ the characterizations for $A_n$ look, as far as I can tell, even more difficult.

What is the value of $ 
\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb P (A_n)
$?

Comment: You can get proper double bars for norms using `\|` instead of `||`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb P (A_n)$ is at most twice the average probability of the random walk to be in $S$ (averaged over the time steps up to $n$). The probability for the walk to be in $S$ goes to $0$ for $n\to\infty$, and thus so does its average over the time steps up to $n$, and thus so does $\mathbb P (A_n)$.

Comment: How do you get the inequality that the probability that a random walk is in $S$ is half the probablity that a random walk is in $S$ for at least half the steps?

Comment: @Sudix: What you wrote is an equation, not an inequality. I used the inequality that the probability that the random walk is in $S$ for more than half its steps is at most twice the average probability for the walk to be in $S$.

Comment: What does "average probability" here mean? And how do you show that inequality? It doesn't strike me as obvious

Comment: @Sudix: I didn't want to repeat the entire answer. "average probability" means what I defined it to mean in the answer: "averaged over the time steps up to $n$".

Comment: @Sudix: Let $X$ denote the number of times the random walk is in $S$ in the time steps up to $n$ and $p$ the average probability to be in $S$ (averaged over time steps up to $n$). By linearity of expectation, $\mathbb E[X]=np$; on the other hand, $\mathbb E[X]\ge\mathbb P(A_n)\frac n2$. Thus $np\ge\mathbb P(A_n)\frac n2$, so $\mathbb P(A_n)\le2p$.

Comment: Thanks, now I get it!